# Do dual chars have to concentrate on the astral to see something there?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4

I'm wondering about dual beings. If for example a runner is a dual being and his team is just fighting a physical threat.

At the same time a spirit (not materialized) comes around a corner and sees the group, does the dual being guy roll for seeing the spirit or only if he consciously concentrates on the astral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dual Natured** beings are inherently aware of both the material world and the astral at all times - that's the very definition of "Dual Natured". The upside is, they take no penalties on either plane. The downside is, they can't turn it off to hide from astral entities.

A Dual Natured being doesn't have to concentrate on one plane or the other. They don't have "astral vision" and "material vision", they just have vision. Game wise, they use separate skills (Assensing and Perception), but that's mostly to keep things consistent with how it works for folks who use Astral Perception.

**Astral Perception**, by contrast, is not a natural state. It is something that must be concentrated on and doing so distracts the user from the material world - hence the penalties imposed.

Comment: so in the above situation a dual being can make an astral perception roll despite concentrating on the physical plane?Ä

Comment: tnx then it is clear